# In TinyMCE, how do you get the font-family of the first line in the editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

So currently, when editor edits a saved text, the toolbar fontName sets to default 'Arial'. Then when I click on the body of the text, finally it changes the fontName to 'Times New Roman', which is what the font family is for the text. I'm guessing this is a normal behavior because I set the default fontName like so:

```
const defaultFont = this.props.defaultFont;
const defaultFontSize = this.props.defaultFontSize;

editor.on('init', function () {
  editor.execCommand('fontName', false, defaultFont);
  editor.execCommand('fontSize', false, defaultFontSize);
});
```

On init, is there a way to set the toolbar fontName to the font-family of the first line of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I put everything in setup function and created a method that returns font-family on the element.

```
getFontFam(elm, property, toolbarFontElm) {
const list = elm.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
if (list) {
  const fontRaw = window.getComputedStyle(list, null).getPropertyValue(property).split(',')[0].replace(/['"]+/g, '');
  const fontUsed = fontRaw.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});;

  toolbarFontElm.innerText = fontUsed;
  return fontUsed;
}
const fontRaw = window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue(property).split(',')[0].replace(/['"]+/g, '');
const fontUsed = fontRaw.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});;

toolbarFontElm.innerText = fontUsed;
return fontUsed;
}
```

and the config:

```
setup: (editor) => {
  // Set default font
  setTimeout(() => {
    const defaultFontSize = this.props.defaultFontSize;
    const iframe = document.getElementById(editor.iframeElement.id);
    const innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('tinymce');
    const toolbarFontElm = document.getElementsByClassName('mce-txt')[0];
    const defaultFont = this.getFontFam(innerDoc, 'font-family', toolbarFontElm);

    editor.on('init', function () {
      editor.execCommand('fontName', false, defaultFont);
      editor.execCommand('fontSize', false, defaultFontSize);
    });
  }, 10);
}
```